# How to deploy Rest API developed using Laravel to production?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have developed rest api using laravel and calling them from Angular 4. Its all working fine on local system as I'm running laravel using "php artisan serve". But when i host it on AWS EC2 Instance as by the same way and when I call api then it gives me 404 error.

I have put all the code in /var/www/html and accessed it like http://domain/api/report but still gives me 404. But when I access public folder like http://domain/public/index.php its working fine.

Please help me with that.

Thank you!

Comment: you have to upload whole project in `root` directory and public folder files in `html` directory of your server

Comment: By that can I access the api like http://domain/api/report ???

Comment: yup you can. because .htaccess done this work for you , if you look in your public directory you can find you .htaccess

Comment: @KaranSadana done. Now it is showing me this error - You don't have permission to access /api/report on this server.

Comment: watch this youtube tutorial hope its help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY6G4K91v0A

Comment: @KaranSadana now its returning Internal Server Error??

Comment: your all directories like app,bootstrap,config etc are going to place inside `var/www/` nd now your project public derector files like your css and javascript , index.php .htaccess all all are going to inside `html` then try to hit your url

Comment: @KaranSadana I did the same sir. But still the same issue?

Comment: solved or not? if not can you show me screenshot of html directory

Comment: @KaranSadana http://54.191.27.33/img

Comment: hey here is your mistake ...i read your comment in below content,, your public structure is `html/public` thats wrong ... i told you to place your public folder files in html like `html/js` , `html/css` , `html/indexphp` like that

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Now I did all as you said. When I access 54.191.27.33/api/reports it shows 404 error with message The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server. Please check URL

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: your project is working http://54.191.27.33/index.php check ,,,and follow my answer for routes see that video tutorial i give in answer

Comment: And please check this link http://54.191.27.33/api/reports it's still giving me the error, can you find that?

Comment: why you don't checking my answer. i provide solution but you dont wanna to listen

Answer (score 1):

please change your document directory path in  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/00-default.conf` this file

you also check your rewrite module is on.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

var/www/html
```

to

```
var/www/html/public
```

after restart server

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What will change of that? I can access public by doing http://domain/public/index.php?

Comment: please change your document root path and enable rewrite module for htaccess

Comment: Still the same error. Not able to access 54.191.27.33/api/report (404 Error)

Comment: you can find an error in the log because without any information I can't help you

Answer (score 1):

So you need to make 2 changes.

Firstly point your application domain to public folder so the step will be :
a.Enable rewrite module with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
b.Change AllowOverride in apache conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

c.Update path from `var/www/html` to `var/www/html/public`

Secondly remove index.php from your url with .htaccess file if you have made some changes in default file (you can find this file in public directory of your project)

Comment: Still the same error. Not able to access http://54.191.27.33/api/report (404 Error)

Comment: can you please share your directory structure here(screenshot)

Comment: my public folder is at /var/www/html/public and all other files like app,routes,config are at /var/www. Is that ok?

Comment: at www or html ?

Comment: public folder is at /var/www/html and all others are at /var/www

Comment: You should move all file /folders in var/www/html

Comment: And then how to access api? Can you give me url example to access api??

Comment: it will be accessible at 54.191.27.33/api

Comment: The setup is still not correct as you are not able to view http://54.191.27.33/index.php

Comment: please see my directory structure http://54.191.27.33/img and this is as suggested by @KaranSadana?

Comment: Yes so as i have mentioned above you need to move all the files in html folder (where your current public folder is), I am not sure what is the reason behind keeping public and other files in separate directory.

Comment: Other option is move public file to www.Also you need to update your question where you have mentioned `I have put all the code in /var/www/html `

Comment: you mentioned that ```Update path from var/www/html to var/www/html/public``` what is the need of it I mean we are not using public folder anywhere as I have put all my files from public folder to ```/var/www/html``` and remaining all the files are at ```/var/www``` so why do I need ```/var/www/html/public```?

Comment: Just to keep simple there is no public folder in http://54.191.27.33/img so please move all the laravel related file from `var/www to var/www/html`

Comment: I did as you said and I have also change my os at instance to Ubuntu 18.04 from AMI Linux, but still 404 is error there. http://35.160.181.252/RenewalHelp/api/reports (All my laravel project is in RenewalHelp directory)

Comment: As you can see http://35.160.181.252/RenewalHelp/public is working so your laravel setup is fine,first just follow the steps  mentioned by me in my answer

Comment: In a terminal use the following commands:
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite

Change AllowOverride in apache conf file:
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Change the AllowOverride from None to All in this block

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
At last, restart apache2
$ sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: or update your .htaccess like below
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Dude still the same error 404. I did everything as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your api is out of the public disk.

To link it just create symbolic link between public/api and api

Comment: Thanks @yegor-keller but how can I do that and How it will redirect to api folder?

Answer (score 0):

For uploading laravel to the server , you have to upload your all laravel directories in `var/www`
and content of the public folder in `html`

laravel did this because of security so no one can access your configuration files like `.env` or any other PHP files which make it more secure

so your output of `var/www` like

`var/www/app
var/www/bootstrap
var/www/config`

and so on

and then output of your `html` is like

`html/js
html/css
html/index.php`

and so on

then your application will work well
and if you facing an issue like you cant access routes then you have to do some rewrite in `apache config` file for this you can watch that video tutorial [rewrite configuration laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY6G4K91v0A)